# Expose Custom DB Tables to Drupal Views Error

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to display an already existing table to Drupal Views. This table exists within my current Drupal Database, along with my Drupal tables.

The table's name is `ACCOUNT_PNL` and I would like to expose the fields in this table to Drupal Views.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://mydons.com/how-to-expose-custom-module-table-to-views-in-drupal/), but when I go and enable this module, I get the following error from my site:

```
DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table <em class="placeholder">ACCOUNT_PNL</em> already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of /var/www/drupal7/includes/database/schema.inc).
```

I understand that the table already exists, but isn't the tutorial code supposed to only "expose" it to Views so I can then use Views to display it?

Perhaps there is an error in my understanding, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you linked to implements [`hook_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) which means Drupal will want to take care of the table implementation for you.

I don't know this for definite but I think Views requires that the table be under Drupal's control when you're exposing custom data.

I don't know of a way to tell the installer to ignore the schema installation, so the simplest thing to do would probably be to rename the custom table temporarily, install the module (allowing Drupal to create the table), then import the data from the temp table into the newly created one.

If you then uninstall the module (not just disable), your custom table and the data will be lost so it's worth keeping a backup if you think that's likely to happen.

Comment: That all seems very complicated. Would you know how I can give my tables(s) to be under the control of Drupal? Or to simply just let Views display the rows in my table?

Comment: I guess you could go into the `system` table and manually set the `status` of your module to `1`...that would make Drupal think the module's already been installed. You'd need to clear the caches after doing that

Comment: If the table already exists in Drupal wouldn't you use hook_schema_alter rather than hook_schema to modify the DB?

Comment: Depending on the usecase you might want to remove `hook_schema` completely. You are using `hook_views_data` in mymodule.views.inc so the database structure is already known to Views. That also makes sure your table won't accidentally be cleared if you would disable the module. This however only applies if you write this for your specific website. When building a module for more people you'd want to create the table for them.

Answer (score 0):

> The tables declared by `hook_schema()` hook will be automatically created when
>   the module is first enabled, and removed when the module is
>   uninstalled.

As there is already `table` in your Drupal database, so you are getting the error that `table already exist` when you install the module.

There is no need of implements `hook_schema()` function in your installation file, if you have already `table` in your database with record.

Or you can implements `hook_schema_alter()` in your module to alter your existing table.